# Samba 4.1.9 returning "access denied" trying to change share perms from Win client

Tags: windows, samba, centos, acl, samba4

UPDATE: version mismatch seemed to stop happening for some reason, although not sure why/at what point.

Have a "public" (within LAN...like [this](http://www.spinics.net/lists/samba/msg116370.html)) read-write share on a CentOS 6.4 box running, according to `/var/log/samba/log.samba`, "samba version 4.1.9-SerNet-RedHat-8.el6."  If I go to a Win7 or Windows Server 2003 box, right-click the share (from Computer Management connected to servername) it already says under the second tab (Share Permissions) that Everyone has Full (all three boxes checked).  Under the third tab (Security), it has all boxes NOT checked for any of the three users listed, Everyone, and these two S-### entries for 1128 and 513 which are the user and group unix owners of most of the files on the share.  Anyway, if I, a domain admins member, try to grant Full Control to Everyone in the Security tab, and hit OK, I get right away an error popup:

---

### Security

Unable to save permission changes on Shared on Samba 4.1.9-SerNet-RedHat-8.el6 (G5).

Access is denied.

---

### Retry   Cancel

So...how can access be denied to a domain admin?  All files on the *nix side have 777 perms.

For the most part the share does actually function with full read/write to everyone, but one (large, complicated, and not at all verbose in its error messages) is complaining about not having permissions somewhere on the tens of thousands of files it uses on the shared drive (it's a program that is designed to be used off a shared drive for its data--"ATP Navigator".)  Hence trying to give full control to everyone to see if it solves that.

FS on which share folder lives is ext4, and has acl and user_xattr enabled on some level.

Domain admins do have SeDiskOperator privilege, I checked using the command-line from centos.

So, why is access denied?